# JOIN MySQL - Two tables (some missing keys)

Tags: mysql, select, join

Let's say I have two tables:

**TabA**

```
+-----+----+
|TabID|Send|
|    1|   5|
|    2|   8|
|    3|  12|
|    4|  16|
+-----+----+
```

**TabB**

```
+-----+--------+
|TabID|Recieved|
|    1|      17|
|    4|       3|
|    5|       2|
|    6|       8|
+-----+--------+
```

And I would like result like this:

```
+-----+----+--------+
|TabID|Send|Recieved|
|    1|   5|      17|
|    2|   8|       3|
|    3|  12|       0|
|    4|  16|       0|
|    5|   0|       2|
|    6|   0|       8|
+-----+----+--------+
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
COALESCE(A.TabID,B.TabID) as TabID,
COALESCE(A.Send,0) as Send,
COALESCE(B.Recieved,0) as Recieved
FROM
TabA AS A
LEFT JOIN
TabB AS B
ON
B.TabID = A.TabID
```

But I got this:

```
+-----+----+--------+
|TabID|Send|Recieved|
|    1|   5|      17|
|    2|   8|       3|
|    3|  12|       0|
|    4|  16|       0|
+-----+----+--------+
```

I'm sure there is a solution in MySQL doc, but I don't know how is this operation called.

Comment: try: `select a.TabID as TabID,
       COALESCE(a.Send, 0) as Send, 
       COALESCE(b.Recieved, 0) as Recieved
from tabA as a
left join tabB as b
 on a.TabID = b.TabID
UNION
select c.TabID as TabID, 
       COALESCE(a.Send, 0) as Send, 
       COALESCE(c.Recieved, 0) as Recieved
from tabA as a
right join tabB as c
 on a.TabID = c.TabID;`  check this [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c4d2/1)